# Parallelize very expensive operation on a table that has a small number of rows in Postgres 13.1

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with a small number of rows where a very expensive function needs to run on each row in a separate worker process as the function is very CPU intensive. I am able to force a parallel sequential scan on the table by setting the storage parameter `parallel_workers` to `max_worker_processes` I've created an easily reproducible example below, with the only significant difference being that the value column would actually be multiple MB in size.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION very_expensive_operation(value anyelement, sleep_time integer=2) RETURNS integer as $$
    BEGIN
        perform pg_sleep(sleep_time);
        return sleep_time;
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql immutable strict parallel safe cost 10000;

CREATE UNLOGGED TABLE expensive_rows (
    id  serial PRIMARY KEY,
    value uuid
) WITH (parallel_workers = 8);
INSERT INTO expensive_rows(value) select gen_random_uuid() identifier from generate_series(1,16);

EXPLAIN ANALYSE VERBOSE

    SELECT
        very_expensive_operation(value,2)
    FROM
      expensive_rows
;
```

```
Gather  (cost=0.00..5312.12 rows=1700 width=4) (actual time=2010.650..32042.558 rows=16 loops=1)
"  Output: (very_expensive_operation(value, 2))"
  Workers Planned: 8
  Workers Launched: 7
  ->  Parallel Seq Scan on public.expensive_rows  (cost=0.00..5312.12 rows=212 width=4) (actual time=286.078..4575.903 rows=2 loops=7)
"        Output: very_expensive_operation(value, 2)"
        Worker 0:  actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=0 loops=1
        Worker 1:  actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=0 loops=1
        Worker 2:  actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=0 loops=1
        Worker 3:  actual time=2002.537..32031.311 rows=16 loops=1
        Worker 4:  actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=0 loops=1
        Worker 5:  actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=0 loops=1
        Worker 6:  actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=0 loops=1
Planning Time: 0.086 ms
Execution Time: 32042.609 ms
```

As you can see from the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` output I am indeed getting a parallel plan, however `very_expensive_function` still inexplicably executes sequentially. If parallelized properly this query should take 4 seconds but instead takes 32 despite 7 additional workers being spawned.

How can I force postgres to allocate 1 CPU core per row/expensive function call without resorting to using dblink?

Comment: It doesn't spread out work one row at a time but in blocks.

Comment: @THX1138 then I would suggest to make a `generated column` with the values of that function and make an index on

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is that all 16 table rows are in a single table block, and a parallel sequential scan assigns ranges of blocks to each worker to scan.

So only one of them scans the single block and executes all 16 function calls.

In a real life example with more rows, the workload would be distributed more evenly. If the table is small, you could artificially bloat the table by setting `fillfactor` to 10 and running `VACUUM (FULL)` on the table. That won't do much for a table as small as this, but could improve parallelization for somewhat bigger tables.

Another silly idea would be to partition the table, so that the rows get split across partitions.

Comment: In the real life example the rows are ~20Mb TOASTed postgis geoms. Due to the nature of the operation I'm running (union/polygonize), it adds overhead / introduces other issues to split the geoms into smaller chunks. I initially thought that the issue might be due to TOAST lowering on disk tuple size, so I set the `toast_tuple_target` to 8160 (max) and then created a dummy text column  filled with characters up to a bit under the block limit, thinking that would result in the rows being distributed to workers evenly -but this had no impact.

Comment: @THX1138 I think toast_tuple_target doesn't do what you think it does.  You probably still only had one page for the whole table.  It stopped after toasting your dummy column, not before.  By combining a dummy column that is large but under the toast limit with a small fillfactor, I get the desired behavior.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe this does work after changing the fillfactor to 10 and adding an extra dummy varchar column just under the toast limit -and works on my actual problem by also setting the large geometry column's storage to EXTERNAL. I did have to triple the row count and still doesn't divide quite as evenly as in the simple example I posted -but performance is 3x faster. Thanks for your help!